# Using imported data in further calculations

Tags: import

I have quite a lot of data in an Excel file, which I have to use in further calculations. The transformation should map a data point with thre coordinates into a two coordinate result. Example: $(r,g,b)\mapsto(r/2 + g, r \, tan(\pi/3)/2)$.

So far I have tried the following, but it doesn't work since the result is the same as the imported data.

```
coords[{r_, g_, b_}] := {r/2 + g, r Tan[Pi/3]/2};
data = Import["file.xlsx"]
coords[data]
```

#### Edit

OK, i'm sorry for not posting the data earlier:

```
{{{"0.1", "0.65", "0.25"}, {"0.8", "0.1", "0.1"}, {"0.7", "0.15", "0.15"}, 
  {"0.6", "0.1", "0.3"}, {"0.5", "0.2", "0.3"}, {"0.4", "0.1", "0.5"}, 
  {"0.3", "0.3", "0.4"}, {"0.2", "0.1", "0.7"}, {"0.1", "0.8", "0.1"}}}
```

Comment: How about `coords/@data`? Without `data` it is difficult to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues... first, the data is in the form of strings, so needs to be changed into numbers (this is the `ToExpression`). The `Flatten` removes an extra pair of brackets, and then you can `Map` the `coords` function onto the `data`. The symbols `/@` are shorthand for this mapping.

```
stringData = {{{"0.1", "0.65", "0.25"}, {"0.8", "0.1", "0.1"}, 
 {"0.7", "0.15", "0.15"}, {"0.6", "0.1", "0.3"}, {"0.5", "0.2", "0.3"}, 
 {"0.4", "0.1", "0.5"}, {"0.3", "0.3", "0.4"}, {"0.2", "0.1", "0.7"}, {"0.1", "0.8", "0.1"}}}; 
data = Flatten[ToExpression[stringData], 1];
coords[{r_, g_, b_}] := {r/2 + g, r Tan[Pi/3]/2};
coords /@ data
```

Your output is then:

```
{{0.7, 0.0866025}, {0.5, 0.69282}, {0.5, 0.606218}, {0.4, 0.519615}, 
 {0.45, 0.433013}, {0.3, 0.34641}, {0.45, 0.259808}, {0.2, 0.173205}, {0.85, 0.0866025}}
```

Comment: it works like clockwork :) thank you! Some of these commands are new to me but, i'll try to get my head around it.

Comment: `Map` is very common -- it's one way to replace a Do or For looping structure. `Flatten` is really useful for removing extra parentheses.

Comment: your explanations are very good, i think i already understand it better now

Comment: @user12073 You can also use `Dot`: `data.Transpose@{{1/2., 1., 0.}, {Tan[Pi/3]/2., 0., 0.}}`, which can be much faster on large data sets.